# How to register_sidebar() without messing up the order?

Tags: plugins, register-sidebar

How do you register a sidebar in a plugin without screwing up the pre-existing registered sidebars? (The ordering of the sidebar registrations, rather than the assigned ID, determines the sidebar data.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function self_deprecating_sidebar_registration(){
  register_sidebar( /* Your arguments here */ );
}

add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'self_deprecating_sidebar_registration' );
```

Most themes will register the sidebar in their functions file, which is included before `init` but after plugins are loaded. Hooking onto `wp_loaded` should guarantee that your sidebar is registered after the theme's.

Comment: I should also add that `wp_loaded` is the latest hook you can reliably use to register the sidebar for both admin and front end.

Comment: Sick. I was about to look up that same information. Thanks!

Comment: Also, can we get some action on this? http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14256

Comment: If you can, attend the IRC dev chat on Thurs and mention the ticket.  Or email a core dev.  Or bring it up on the wp-hackers list.